# Abbreviating numbers with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, numbers

How would I abbreviate numbers using Ruby?

```
1,518,181 to 1.5M
481,191 to 481k
95,562 to 95k
```

For this particular project I happen to be using Rails, so if there's some obscure helper method I'm not aware of, it'd be fine to use that here.

Comment: try this helper http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human_size

Comment: @Sam That's perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Moderator can delete/close this.

Answer (score 1):

There is [#number_to_human](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human):

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
number_to_human(1500000) # => "1.5 Million"
```